# problem related to continuity of a function

Tags: analysis

If $f:S\to \mathbb R$ is convex ,
continuous function  and we've $x_1\leq x_2~~~$ s.t. $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$and $x'=\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2,$ where $\lambda \in (0,1).$ Also given $f(x') \gt f(x_2)$  .

then I can't understand how did the following conclude from continuity of $f$
:

> there must exist $\delta \in (0,1)$ s.t. $f(\mu x'+(1-\mu)x_2)\gt f(x_2)$ and $f(x')\gt f(\delta x'+(1-\delta)x_2)$ $\forall$ $\mu$ $\in$ [$\delta,1]$.

Kindly help..

Comment: i think it can be concluded from jensen's inequality @spectraa

Comment: @Boris  the function is given to be convex also..

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the intermediate value theorem.
$f(x') > f(x_2).$  It is possible that f(x') > f(x_2) for all $x\in(x',x_2)$.  In which case delta can be anything $\in (0,1)$.  Suppose f(x) passes to some number below $f(x_2)$ on the way.  There must be a first time when f(x) passes below $f(x_2)$ and delta defines that sub interval $(x',\delta x' + (1-\delta)x_2)$ where for all x in that sub interval $f(x')>f(x) > f(x_2)$